# Trigger.io: How do you use one codebase to scale/fit the content onto multiple tablets?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tablet, trigger.io

I'm building a tablet app using trigger.io. Right now I'm using just JS scripts on different pages, instead of using something like Backbone, to manage app logic. I'm also using bootstrap for the front end.

I am developing/testing on a Nexus 7. However, I have to make sure the app layout works on both this as well as the 'new' iPad (iPad 3). The two devices have slightly different aspect ratios and completely different screen resolutions.

The header and footer should be fine since they work on absolute page values. However, how can I scale/fit the content between them?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a great place to start for help with this.

Responsive design techniques (which can make Bootstrap behave properly in a mobile website for different devices) will work for a Trigger.io app too.

For a starting point, I'd recommend a fluid grid with responsive design features enabled. See the responsive utility classes for more fine-grained control.